# 2 clicks & doubleclicks creating lines and dots on a picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I've been struggling with this for a few days and have been worried about asking for assistance as I've been afraid I wouldn't explain it very well and it may seem overly convoluted.  But I've reached that point where I don't know what else to do.  So here goes.

I have a picturebox with an image.  This originally started where I just need to click one spot on the image and then a second spot and a line was drawn between the 2 points.  A list of p1 and p2 contained (p1.X, p1.Y) and (p2.X, p2.Y).  The "Zone" they created this line is also logged which is determined by the RGB value of where they made the line.

This works great.  I also have a button to remove lines you've created by just removing the last point added to the list and refreshing the picturebox.

Then a bit of a monkey wrench was thrown in when they asked for a dot to be created of a certain size.  So I made a small red dot.png image.  And then setup a doubleclick event so that when they double click it adds the dot.png to the picturebox at the location they double clicked at.  In a good way, because creating the lines is created by clicking 2 points, this also had the benefit of logging the p1 and p2 location as well and the clicked Zone.  So I was killing 2 birds with one stone.

However the problem is with removing the dots.  Remember originally I was just able to remove the last entry for p1 and p2.  However this will not remove the dot since its a separate image, it will just remove the p1,p2 location of dot.png.

So I figured I'd create a separate removal button for clearing the last created dots.  I don't want to do it this way, I rather have 1 button but in this case I don't see how that would be possible.

I was trying to create a list of dots and then add the dot to the picturebox but I keep running into issues with that.  Removing 1 dot is fine.  But if you have 2 dots and try to remove 1 you get an out of bounds error.  So I figured it was because I wasn't using the dots from the list, that even though there was 2 dots on the image that it was actually just 1 as far as the app was concerned so removing 1 was like removing them all.

But here's what I have.  Hopefully your head doesn't hurt.

```
private void RemoveDot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dbldot.Images.Count != 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Controls.RemoveAt(dbldot.Images.Count - 1);
        p1List.RemoveAt(p1List.Count - 1);
        p2List.RemoveAt(p2List.Count - 1);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}


private void RemoveLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (p1List.Count != 0 && p2List.Count != 0)
    {
        p1List.RemoveAt(p1List.Count - 1);
        p2List.RemoveAt(p2List.Count - 1);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }


void picture_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doubletime ++;

    PictureBox dot = new PictureBox();
    {
        dot.Name = "reddot";
        dot.Size = new Size(16, 16);
        dot.Image = Resources.red_dot_32;
        dot.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        dot.Location = new Point(p2.X - 7, p2.Y - 7);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < doubletime; x++)
    {
        dbldot.Images.Add(dot.Image);
    }

    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(dot);
}


private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        if (p1.X == 0)
        {
            p1.X = e.X;
            p1.Y = e.Y;

            var color = zoneMap1.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
            if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("1");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("2");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 150, 1))
            {
                Zone1.Add("3");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("4");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("5");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255))
            {
                Zone1.Add("6");
            }
            else if (color == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0))
            {
                Zone1.Add("7");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This void is not within the void area.");
                p1.X = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            p2.X = e.X;
            p2.Y = e.Y;

            p1List.Add(p1);
            p2List.Add(p2);

            Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
            btnPre.Enabled = true;
            p1.X = 0;
        }
    }
}


private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < p1List.Count; x++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

So ultimately someone can help me come up with a proper way to add the dot.png when they double click.  Retain the ability to place the dot.png where they double clicked, retain logging its location and the ability to remove that dot.png.  Either with a separate button or preferably within the remove line button.

Comment: This sounds like a case of feature creep. It might be worth your time to take a step back and ask if there's a way to redesign your program in such a way to make the actions simpler to design.

Comment: I've given that some thought.  But I'm not sure if there is a much simpler way, but maybe there is a different way?  I think if there is a different way it lies in how I add and remove the dot.  And hopefully that's what someone can help with.

Comment: Well for one, polymorphism will go a long way in streamlining the design. Instead of storing a list of lines and dots, store a list of shapes, and define a `Line` and `Dot` class that inherits from `Shape`. Have the `Shape` class define an abstract method called `Paint` that takes a `Graphics` object as a parameter that the `Line` and `Dot` classes can override. And when you remove the last line/dot from the list, you are just removing the last shape (which could be either a line or a dot). Behold the wonders of object-oriented programming.

Comment: @Abion47 I'll be honest with you, most of what you said was Chinese to me.  I haven't been doing this long, most of which I'm learning as I go.  So I'll have to research, read, find examples..etc ..etc  I just hope they give me some time.